# Invariant violation while importing react native element UI framework

Tags: react-native, react-redux

please  i  have been trying  to work  with  react-native Element framework  but i get the  error  below  , but  when  i remove the  import  very  thing  works  fine , i tried  creating  other projects  but  i still get  the same  error , but as   i said as soon as i remove the  import  the  app  works  fine  .

error i  get

[image]

my  main.js

```
            import React from 'react'
        import { 
          StyleSheet, 
          Text, 
          View,
          StatusBar,
          TextInput,
          TouchableHighlight,
          TouchableOpacity
        } from 'react-native';
        import {Input,Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
//import { Container, Header, Content, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Text } from 'native-base';


export default  class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Input
      placeholder='INPUT WITH ICON'
      leftIcon={
        <Icon
          name='user'
          size={24}
          color='black'
        />
      }
    />
    )
  }
}

        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
            container: {
              flex: 1,
              alignItems: 'stretch',
              justifyContent: 'flex-start',
              paddingTop:20,
              backgroundColor:'#aaa'

            }
        });

        export default Main;



then  my App.js 


import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {configureStore} from './app/store';
import Main from  './app/components/Main'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reducers from './app/reducer';


const store = createStore(reducers);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={configureStore()}>
        <Main/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
})
```

;

error  after  @Colin update

[image]

Comment: What is `container`? Does `react-native-elements` have a `Container` component?

Comment: thanks  for the fast  reply  i removed  it  but   but still not  change

Comment: You removed it where?

Comment: i mean just removed  it  from  my code  but having the same error

Comment: Can you update your code please?

Comment: @Colin  updated the  code

Comment: And what's the new error?

Comment: @Colin  the same error  as the above but points to render()  function in  the  Main

Comment: Can you paste the actual error please?

Comment: @Colin  it is the same error as above

Comment: It can't be the same error, since the error above includes a reference to `container`, which you have removed.

Comment: @Colin  sorry , yes i just updated  the  question

Comment: Can you make a CodeSandbox example, and I'll take a look.

Comment: @Colin okay  let me do it thanks

Answer (score 0):

As asked by @Colin in the comment section, react-native-elements does not have any container component.

Thats the reason for your issue.

Edited: I request you to go through this [link](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.0/overview.html) (its a link to the official documentation) and utilise the components which are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  all  ,
i found  my mistake  actually  the doc  i was  using was 1.0.0 while the  node version   i was using is  version 0.9 . thanks